# dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: files list file for package 'linux-generic' is missing final newline

Tags: apt, dpkg

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apt apt-transport-https apt-utils dpkg libapt-inst2.0 libapt-pkg5.0 ntpdate
  oracle-java8-installer oracle-java8-set-default thermald
10 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/4,389 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8,192 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'linux-generic' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I already tried the usual stuff like:

```
 sudo dpkg --configure -a 
 sudo apt-get -f install
 sudo apt-get clean
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Any help, thanks!

```
cat -net /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-generic.list
     1  ^LbM-BM-^FRq^MU^Evalueq^NK^HubU^Mcertificationq^ONU^Hoverviewq^PNU$
     2  updated_atq^QNU^Vavailable_translationsq^RNU^Dyearq^SMM-CM-^]^GU^Fimagesq^TNU^Bidq^UNU^Ipaused_atq^VNU^Eindex
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `cat -net /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-generic.list`

Comment: I tried copying the linux-generic.list from a good ubuntu machine and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Copied how exactly? the `cat -net` output you posted earlier appears to show a mess of Windows control characters (`CR` endings and byte order mark) - did you use a word processing program (Word / LibreOffice) by any chance?

Comment: the corrupted linux-generic.list was output was copied from putty
I used scp to copy from a working ubuntu machine to the corrupted one, replacing the bad one

Answer (score 31):

I had similar issues with the following error:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'libboost-regex1.55.0:armhf' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

However, the folder `/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux` didn't exist on my system, as in previous post. (I was running Raspbian on a Raspberry pi 3)

I moved the following files:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libboost-regex1.55.0:armhf.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libboost-regex1.55.0:armhf.list
```

Then ran:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

It fixed the problem for me.

Comment: For this particular question, you would run: `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-generic.list` and then you might need to reinstall the package: `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-generic`

Comment: Thanks that worked. 
BUT I had to do a `sudo apt-get install --reinstall <missing_library>`
as the final step

Comment: Worked for me with a the aforementioned reinstallation. Otherwise, throws "dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'PACKAGENAME' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed"

Answer (score 8):

I finally had some time to fix this on my own.  For future reference

I moved all the linux* files to somewhere else. ex: ~/ (home) `sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux* ./`

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

That fixed it

Comment: Did not work for me. It did add extra errors: `dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-base' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-libc-dev:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed`

Answer (score 8):

Firstly you have to remove that missing file

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-generic.list
```

Now you can again reinstall it

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic --reinstall
```

Comment: Don't be afraid! I had an issue with `nginx` and after removing the file I had the same issue with `'perl-openssl-defaults:arm64`. So I also removed this file and then `apt install nginx --reinstall` successfully ran!  BTW: The files returned some gibberisch upon `cat`. Either my SD card is failing or there was a problem when I removed some packages.

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar issue and resolved it a different way, so I thought I'd share what I did.  While attempting a **sudo apt upgrade** I received the following dpkg error:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'python3-xdg' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I found python3-xdg.list in the **/var/lib/dpkg/info/** directory and ran cat on the file.  What printed out was something like this, with the command prompt immediately following the contents:

```
user@device:/var/lib/dpkg/info$ cat python3-xdg.list
sEDUsEDUsEDUuser@device:/var/lib/dpkg/info$
```

I thought I'd try editing the file, giving it the **missing final newline**, so printing the file would then display:

```
user@device:/var/lib/dpkg/info$ cat python3-xdg.list
sEDUsEDUsEDU
user@device:/var/lib/dpkg/info$
```

After this I had no more issues.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this kind of error and I solved it very easily.

```
Selecting previously unselected package curl.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'm17n-db' contains empty filename
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Here how I solved this error:

Go to `/var/lib/dpkg/info/m17n-db.list`
Then open `m17n-db.list` in text editor/

You will see a empty new line at the last line of this file's text as like this:

[image: m17n-db.list file's text]

You just need to do this:

1. Delete the empty new line if there is one.
2. Then save the file with administrator password.
   there we go. All problems are fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'rockchip-fstab' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

`sudo dpkg --configure -a` also did not work for me.

So, I had to edit by `vim /var/lib/dpkg/info/rockchip-fstab.list` as:

`/.` from `V\H`

Which fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This answer beffore doesn't work for me.

This work for me:

```
# First go to this path, to edit status
cd /var/lib/dpkg
# Backup status file
sudo cp status status.bak
# Edit status file
sudo nano status

# We are going to search for corrup package and delete entire block
# the first line start with
Package: apport
# The last line to delete is the "line before" of "new line" next to the "new start of pakage"
# Save the file
# Note: Check images of example at end

# Check for errors
sudo apt upgrade
# Fix broken package
sudo apt --fix-broken install

# Optional: delete file backup
sudo rm status.bak
```

Delete lines from status file
**Example with package: apport**
[image]

Delete thouse lines before the new line
**Example to where to delete:**
[image]

**Reference:** [Solución: dpkg: error fatal irrecuperable, abortando. E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)](https://ubuntinux.blogspot.com/2020/03/solucion-dpkg-error-fatal-irrecuperable.html)