# unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: files list file for package 'tzdata' is missing final newline

Tags: apt, dpkg

I came up with this issue since yesterday

I already checked some existing posts from where I did the following:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux* /tmp/mcrose/
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I got some issues again so I runned

```
sudo apt-get clean
dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and then I got these errors:

```
mcrose@home:~$ sudo apt upgrade -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  adobe-flash-properties-gtk adobe-flashplugin budgie-welcome chromium-browser chromium-browser-l10n chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
  gnome-software gnome-software-common gnome-software-plugin-snap libssl1.0.0 libxml2 openssl python-libxml2 ubuntu-fan vivaldi-stable
15 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 147 MB of archives.
After this operation, 47,7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://py.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/universe amd64 chromium-browser-l10n all 63.0.3239.84-0ubuntu0.17.04.1 [2.640 kB]
Get:2 http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable/main amd64 vivaldi-stable amd64 1.13.1008.36-1 [49,3 MB]                                
Get:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty/partner amd64 adobe-flash-properties-gtk amd64 1:20171212.1-0ubuntu0.17.04.1 [143 kB]
Get:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntubudgie/backports/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 budgie-welcome all 0.5.8 [5.084 kB]                       
Get:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty/partner amd64 adobe-flashplugin amd64 1:20171212.1-0ubuntu0.17.04.1 [9.781 kB]          
Get:6 http://py.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/universe amd64 chromium-browser amd64 63.0.3239.84-0ubuntu0.17.04.1 [73,7 MB]   
Get:2 http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable/main amd64 vivaldi-stable amd64 1.13.1008.36-1 [49,3 MB]                                
Get:7 http://py.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/universe amd64 chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra amd64 63.0.3239.84-0ubuntu0.17.04.1 [1.010 kB]
Get:8 http://py.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 libssl1.0.0 amd64 1.0.2g-1ubuntu11.4 [1.080 kB]                      
Get:9 http://py.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 libxml2 amd64 2.9.4+dfsg1-2.2ubuntu0.3 [698 kB]                      
Get:10 http://py.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 openssl amd64 1.0.2g-1ubuntu11.4 [491 kB]                           
Get:11 http://py.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 gnome-software-plugin-snap amd64 3.22.7-0ubuntu3.17.04.8 [27,5 kB]  
Get:12 http://py.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 gnome-software amd64 3.22.7-0ubuntu3.17.04.8 [305 kB]               
Get:13 http://py.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 gnome-software-common all 3.22.7-0ubuntu3.17.04.8 [2.481 kB]        
Get:14 http://py.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 python-libxml2 amd64 2.9.4+dfsg1-2.2ubuntu0.3 [140 kB]              
Get:15 http://py.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-fan all 0.12.8~17.04.1 [34,7 kB]                             
Fetched 134 MB in 18min 22s (121 kB/s)                                                                                                  
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-sound-base' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-image-extra-4.10.0-42-generic' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-tools-4.10.0-40' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-headers-4.10.0-40' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-base' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-libc-dev:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-tools-4.10.0-19' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-tools-4.10.0-19-generic' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-headers-4.10.0-42-generic' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-tools-4.10.0-42' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-image-extra-4.10.0-40-generic' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-tools-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-tools-4.10.0-42-generic' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-generic' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-tools-4.10.0-40-generic' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-image-4.10.0-40-generic' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-headers-4.10.0-42' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-headers-4.10.0-40-generic' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-tools-generic' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-image-generic' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-firmware' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-headers-generic' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'tzdata' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I'm using Ubuntu Budgie

```
mcrose@home:~$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 17.04 \n \l
mcrose@home:~$ uname -a
Linux home 4.10.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 4 14:38:01 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
mcrose@home:~$
```

Comment: Have you messed up */var/lib/apt/lists/* with  */var/lib/dpkg/info/linux**? I suggest to bring */var/lib/dpkg/info/linux** back. From your message it is not clear what problem you are solving. Why you move */var/lib/dpkg/info/linux** instead of */var/lib/dpkg/info/tzdata**? Please update your post with the output of `tail -n 10 /var/lib/dpkg/info/tzdata.list`.

Comment: @N0rbert I saw that moving in a [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/909719/dpkg-unrecoverable-fatal-error-aborting-files-list-file-for-package-linux-ge), may be I just misunderstood what to move, and, since I restarted the system, that folder has gone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command (re-)moves the package meta-data and is a bad idea:

```
mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux* /tmp/mcrose/
```

The files in `/var/lib/dpkg` are part of the internal state of the Debian package manager and supposed to be manipulated *exclusively* with the `dpkg` application or library. It generally is a bad idea to touch anything in `/var/lib/dpkg` *directly* unless you know *really, really* well what you're doing.

---

Since the package meta-data was removed or corrupted you should reinstall these packages:

```sh
dpkg-query -Wf '${Status;1} ${Package}:${Architecture}\n' 'linux*' tzdata |
sed -ne 's/^i //p' |
xargs -rd '\n' -- sudo apt-get install -f --reinstall
```

It's possible that `dpkg` still complains about a malformed file list of `tzdata` in which case your can remove it entirely and retry its reinstallation:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/tzdata.*list
```

---

I suspect that more packages may have been corrupted. You can verify their integrity as described in [Is there a Ubuntu sanity check?](/q/57704/175814) with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install debsums
sudo debsums_init
sudo debsums --changed --silent
```

then reinstall mentioned packages manually with

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: He moved these list-files. They are not corrupted. His system is broken and we do not know how. `debsums` of course may help. With **unrecoverable fatal error** he may not be able to install `debsums` I think.

Comment: @N0rbert: The package *meta-data* is certainly corrupted/removed and a reinstallation of the packages in question will recreate the meta-data and thus fix the issue.

Comment: Did you see `sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux* /tmp/mcrose/` in OP question? It is self-destruction. But your solution seems to be useful, of course. Let's wait reaction from OP.

Comment: @N0rbert: Yes, I saw that. That doesn't change anything about my suggested fix. I could clarify that the aforementioned command is a bad idea.

Comment: hi guys, both answers and comment did clarified what I did wrong
I just first remove the **tzdata** list, then I run **dpkg-query -Wf...**

after reinstalling everthing, I run apt-get upgrade and...
everything works fine now

thanks you both