# libopenmpt-modplug1:amd64

Tags: apt, dpkg, sudo, deb

dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
files list file for package 'libopenmpt-modplug1:amd64' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

**How can I fix this. cant install or remove anyting using "sudo apt" aslo deb, dpkg is not working.**

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/909719/dpkg-unrecoverable-fatal-error-aborting-files-list-file-for-package-linux-ge.

Comment: already try this. but not working